# Multi-processing skip beginning

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am quite new to python and the multi-processing module. I want to know how to make the process skip the beginning so it doesn't repeat it. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
print("Doing something!!!")
```

Code:

```
import multiprocessing

print("Doing something!!!")

def stuff():
    print("Doing stuff")

if __name__  == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=stuff)
    p1.start()
```

Output:

```
Doing something!!!
Doing something!!!
Doing stuff
```

Desired output:

```
Doing something!!!
Doing stuff
```

Comment: if you are on windows, you can't. If you are on macos or linux, you can use fork instead of spawn using: [`multiprocessing.set_start_method("fork")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method). you should probably read up on the difference to learn the implications of spawn vs fork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `multiprocessing` [Programming Guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) in the documentation.

On systems that use the "spawn" or "forkserver" methods of creating processes:

> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process).

Your script is being imported into every process, so it will run any global code in all processes.  Just move anything global into the `if __name__ == '__main__':` section:

```py
import multiprocessing

def stuff():
    print("Doing stuff")

if __name__  == '__main__':
    print("Doing something!!!")
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=stuff)
    p1.start()
```

This insures the function `stuff()` will be imported and defined in every process, but your `print` will only run once in the main process.